# Returning directory address from tkinter button

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I am attempting to create a program to pull a directory address found in one function and use that address in another. To open a file browser, I am using a tkinter button. Can anyone provide some insight as to the fix for this?

```
def openFile():
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/")
    return directory
def callback():
    path = str(directory)

dirButton = Button(Frame1, text="Choose", command=openFile)
dirButton.pack()

nextButt = Button(Frame1, text="Next", command=callback)
nextButt.pack()
```

Comment: Almost this exact question has been asked two or three times this week already. Did you do any research before asking?

Comment: I have, however to no avail. Several have suggested adding 'return...' would remedy the issue, I have not had any success.

Comment: Nevermind, just learned the value of global variables! Sorry for taking up your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remedy this by setting the variable 'directory' as a global variable.

```
def openFile():  
    global directory
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/")
    return

def callback():
    path = str(directory)

dirButton = Button(Frame1, text="Choose", command=openFile)
dirButton.pack()

nextButt = Button(Frame1, text="Next", command=callback)
nextButt.pack()
```

Comment: you don't need to call `str` on `directory`, because `directory` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = str(directory)
```

Should be

```
path = str(openFile())
```

This line runs the function `openFile()` and stores what the function returns in `path`. Now if you really want to have 2 functions an easy fix would be:

```
def openFile():
    global directory
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/")
def callback():
    global directory
    path = str(directory)
```

Here directory is global so is the same in both functions.
Also when giving a command to a button what you are lookingn for is

```
command=lambda:openFile())
```

(Don't forget to add these "()" at the end when you are calling a function)